# ajax post global function vs repeat the same function for each request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have something that i do not understand . 
I do  have a global function AjaxPost() 
that take url and data than send them to backend .
it calls the function but the parameters are always null .

So i take the same content of the function and used it directly in the request , it works perfectly . 
this One Doesn't work  //example : AjaxPost("/Road/DeleteRoad", road);

```
function AjaxPost(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}
```

this one works perfectly

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/Road/DeleteRoad",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(road)
    });
```

Here the action method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRoad([FromBody]r road)
    {
        int.TryParse(road.RoadID, out int RoadID);
        if (RoadID > 0)
        {
            await _road.DeleteRoad(RoadID);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Here is the class r

```
  public class r
    {
        public string RoadID { get; set; }
    }
```

Here Is The Road object 
//for example :

```
  var road ={
    RoadID :4,
    }
```

Comment: Since this is a front end issue, I would remove the unnecessary ASP.net code and add the code for the jQuery including where and how is "road" defined is the most obvious.

Comment: `data` needs to have the format like `var data = { "RoadID" :"hello" };` How do you use your AjaxPost?

Comment: @xing zou i have tried also the one you have mentioned, it doesnt work

Comment: How do you try that?What is your `road` of `AjaxPost("/Road/DeleteRoad", road);`?Could you update the thread to tell us how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @XingZou Done My friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are not passing the road parameter correctly?

The following code works, sending two calls to the server. The server correctly retrieves the *RoadID* value. Here's the javascript:

```
"use strict";

$(document).ready(() => {
    var road = { RoadID: 4 };

    // First call
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/home/DeleteRoad",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(road)
    });

    // Second call
    ajaxPost("/home/DeleteRoad", road);
}

function ajaxPost(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
}
```

The C# code is:

```
public class Road
{
    public string RoadID { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteRoad([System.Web.Http.FromBody]Road road)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Road ID = { road.RoadID }");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The server's output is:

```
Road ID = 4
Road ID = 4
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I will reply after 4 hours from now . the project im working on is not with me here ,and for sure i will make some screen shot